# Firebase/Angularfire collection structure changes not refreshing on client side

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire

Am I the only one having issues when I update the model in Angular to a collection document in firebase and change the structure (added a new object with arrays) and the frontend (browser clients) do not update the structure unless I clear browser cache?

Any suggestions on what this could be? Hope I explained the situation as clear as possible.

Using latest Angular/AngularFire 13.2/7.3 (not using compat for any calls)

Comment: Even tried CTRL+R to refresh the app (the files/model does update but not the data feed)

Comment: Do you have a service worker / PWA in place?

Comment: @AndrewAllen Yes I do, I actually have something similar to this https://www.joshmorony.com/create-a-pwa-with-angular-service-workers-in-ionic-4  Updating the files is not an issue, it refreshes it (I have github push to firebase hosting for CI) It's just the document data/object structures that are the issue that won't update

Comment: It does look like I may need to implement this though https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-communications